# Can an USB TV receiver by Pace Micro Technology work in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, tv

A friend got hold of a USB device that seems to be a Sky TV receiver. It has a USB cable on one side and an antenna F connector on the other. The model number is S-IM25-700 and it shows up in lsusb as:

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bf0:c289 Pace Micro Technology PLC

Do I have any hope of watching broadcast TV in Linux with it?

[image]

Comment: what is your kernel version? **uname -r**  Can you list the relevant parts of **dmesg**.  Do a **dmesg -c** (to clear previous messages) Plug the card in and do **dmesg** and report results.

Comment: You may also need software for this - Its unlikely someone without the exact same piece of kit can answer this but this question might do better as a "How do I use this to watch TV on my computer" question, than a "Can I use this" question.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  FYI: Linux has plenty of free software for viewing TV.  I have struggled many long and hard hours and various tuners and it is always comes down to having the drivers if yes **yay** if no drivers your doomed.  The kernel has a version of the linux-dvb drivers built-in, but are of course always behind.  I don't know if there website hardware support list is current with the current drivers, but my gut instinct say **no**.  All the failures I have had were because of no or poor drivers.

Comment: Oh, naturally, My bigger point was the tone of the question, and trying to work out what the OP has tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

[Hardware compatibility charts](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hardware_Device_Information)

I have no idea how well this list is maintained.

The best option is to see the results of **dmesg**.

Having the most modern kernel possible also significantly increases your chances for success as the kernel has a version of the drivers built-in.

IF your linux has a script/program called **update-pciids** and **update-usbids.sh** I suggest you run both reboot.

```
 **dmesg -c** clear hundreds of useless (to us) entries.
```

plug in device

```
  **dmesg**
```

report results.